# SELECT a category with it sub categories and put them into a DataGridView without category duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datatable, duplicates

I'm sorry about the not clear title but I don't know how to explain what I want exactly, so it would be easier with pictures.

Programming language : C#

I have three tables : `voltage`, `catenary_type` and `type_into_voltage`

In the table `voltage` we have the name of the voltage levels,
in `catenary_type` the name of the catenary types and 
in `type_into_voltage` we can associate a voltage level to a catenary type.

I want to show in a `DataGridView` all the catenary types associated to their voltage levels, so I'm actually selecting data with this code that return a DataTable :

```
internal DataTable SelVoltType()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection connection = Program.GetOpenedSqlConnection())
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tiv.id_voltage, volt.name 'Tension', tiv.id_type, cattype.name as 'Types de caténaire' " +
                "FROM [allocation_schematic.types].type_into_voltage tiv " +
                "INNER JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].catenary_type cattype ON cattype.id = tiv.id_type " +
                "INNER JOIN [allocation_schematic.types].voltage volt ON volt.id = tiv.id_voltage; ", connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                DataAdapter.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
```

and I put it straight to the `DataGridView.DataSource`.

It gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMZ1l.png)

But I want it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGJRL.png) without the duplicated voltage levels

Could anyone help me please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to remove voltage after the table is created.  Try following :

```
           string oldVoltage = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string tension = (string)dt.Rows[i]["Tension"];
                if (tension == oldVoltage)
                {
                    dt.Rows[i]["Tension"] = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    oldVoltage = tension;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nice it works well thanks ! If you or anybody has an SQL solution for this it may be useful because if we have a lot of sub categories it takes a long time for the program to look at each value etc.. But this solution is enough for me ! Thanks !